# Regular Expression: Allow letters, numbers, and spaces (with at least one letter not number)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using this regex (`/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/`) to accept letters, numbers, spaces and underscores. I want to change it like this that it takes the combination of number and the character but not only the number.

Comment: try this /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to allow a string that begins with at least one letter and optionally is followed by number or underscore or space.

Try this: `/^(?:[A-Za-z]+)(?:[A-Za-z0-9 _]*)$/` at this **[online regex tester](http://regex101.com/#javascript)**.

This should work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/
```

This allows for 0 or more of each of the outside groups, and 1 or more of the inner group (letters only).  A string of only digits will fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[\w\s]+$/
```

**\w** allows letters, numbers and underscores

**\s** allow spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s_]+$`

This expression has a negative lookahead to verify that the string is not only numbers. See it in action with [regexr](http://regexr.com/?31n8g)